# Nagios, плагин check_mem.sh не работает

Tags: ubuntu, плагин, мониторинг

Помогите, пожалуйста, никак не могу совладать с плагином check_mem.sh
https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/System-Metrics/Memory/Check-mem-%28by-Nestor%40Toronto%29/details

Все гайды, что нашел - использовал, все равно не работает, в веб-интерфейсе пишет, что не удалось получить данные от плагина "(No output returned from plugin)".

Если запустить его из командной строки, то все хорошо, возврат есть:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/test0# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.sh -w 80 -c 90
Memory: CRITICAL Total: 975 MB - Used: 937 MB - 96% used!|TOTAL=975;;;; USED=937;;;; CACHE=221;;;; BUFFER=14;;;;
```

В nrpe.cfg указал:

```
command[check_mem]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.sh -w 80 -c 90
```

На самом сервере Nagios в test0.cfg (конфиг файл удаленной машины)
указал следующее:

```
define service {
     use                        generic-service
     host_name                  test0
     service_description        Memory Usege1
     check_command              check_nrpe!check_mem
}
```

В commands.cfg указал:

```
define command{
     command_name   check_mem
     command_line   $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c check_mem 
}
```

Nrpe на удаленной машине работает, вот:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/nagios-plugins/config# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 192.168.239.136
NRPE v2.15
```

## Дополнение 1.0

С сервера Нагиос послал запрос к удаленной машине и успешно получил ответ!

```
 root@ubuntu:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 192.168.239.136 -c check_mem
 Memory: WARNING Total: 975 MB - Used: 850 MB - 87% used!|TOTAL=975;;;; USED=850;;;; CACHE=305;;;; BUFFER=44;;;;
```

В веб-интерфейсе все равно та же ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Не знаю, какой шаг стал решающим, но у меня все заработало

1. chmod +x to check_mem.sh
2. удалил описание из test0.cfg
3. добавил описание в services_nagios2.cfg и указал hostgroup debian-servers
4. потом рестартанул service nagios3